# HTML5 Video Tag access Progress Events Properties Loaded and Total

Tags: html, angular, html5-video, dom-events

I've been following the instructions on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/progress, but I am not able to access/get any values for Loaded and Total properties of the Progress Event for the HTML5 video element. Here's my code:

HTML5:

```
    <video id="myVideo" #myVideo #inlineVideo src="https://movie.mp4"
class="inline-video" (click)="videoControls()" playsinline autoplay="true" [muted]="mute" preload="auto" loop>Video not loaded yet</video>
```

JS:

```
 var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
 vid.addEventListener("progress", (returnValue) => {
      console.log('progress: ', returnValue.loaded, returnValue.total)
    });
```

I'm using Angular2+ and Ionic 3.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use event in angular you have to do event binding like this don't use javascript native addEventListener to listen event .Change your code like this

**HTML**

```
<video id="myVideo" #myVideo #inlineVideo src="https://movie.mp4"
    class="inline-video" (click)="videoControls()" (progress)="onProgress($event)" playsinline autoplay="true" [muted]="mute" preload="auto" loop>Video not loaded yet</video>
```

**Ts**

```
onProgress($event){
console.log($event)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does trigger (3 times for my short video), but here is all I see in the $event object: "{ isTrusted": true }". How can I get the values of Loaded and Total properties?

Comment: Works as expected. I am getting all the properties. Thanks.

Comment: @PawanPillai You are welcom!

Comment: I would've liked an example as to how to access the properties, like `duration` :-/ anyway best answer I've found so far.